# Firebase Async Function Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I have node.js v8.3.0, and have this in my package.json:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.3.0"
  }
```

And my test code for await/async:

```
async function x() {
    return "test";
}

exports.asyncTest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => async function() {
    response.end(await x());
});
```

Expected output: `test`
Observed output:

```
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:12
async function x() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:372:24)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Cloud Functions for Firebase runtime is currently Node.js v6.x, so async/await is not supported. There is an expectation that Node v8.x will be supported sometime after it enters Long-Term Support (LTS).

In the meantime, you'll need to use a transpiler like Babel or TypeScript to take advantage of async/await.

Comment: FYI: Not sure who downvoted this, but it is the correct answer. I'm a Firebaser and work closely with the Cloud Functions team.

Comment: Thanks for the info, do you have an idea when will v7.6 be supported?

Comment: We don't announce specific timelines for future work, but will be sometime after October 31 (which is when Node.js v8 goes LTS).

Comment: No -- just that Node v8 will happen sometime after Cloud Functions reaches general availability. We recommend using [e.g. TypeScript](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/improve-productivity-with-typescript.html) for async/await support in the meantime.